# An inequality regarding macroscopic/microscopic systems

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

In some textbooks, it has been written that:

We shall call a system microscopic if it is rough of atomic dimensions, or smaller. On the other hand, we shall call a system macroscopic when it is large enough to be visible in the ordinary sense. This is a rather inexact definition. The exact definition depends on the number of particles in the system, which we shall call $N$. A system is macroscopic if:
$1/\sqrt{N} << 1$

---

I have some questions in this regard.

First:
Is this definition scientific and popular? How can I find its source or probable proof?

Second: If we re-write the inequality, we will conclude:
$N >> 1$
So, why don't people write the inequality in this form? And why they twist it to a more complicated form?

Third:
Is there a more accurate definition for macroscopic and microscopic systems in valid physics references?

Thank you

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: For example:
https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/sm1/Thermal.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author explains why he chose this parameterization on page 9 ([Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics, R. Fitzpatrick](http://Thermodynamic%20systems%20are%20ideally%20suited%20to%20astatistical%20approach,%20because%20of%20the%20enormousnumbers%20of%20particles%20that%20they%20contain.%20Statistical%20arguments%20actually%20get%20more%20exact%20as%20the%20numbersinvolved%20get%20larger.%20For%20example,%20consider%20an%20opinion%20poll%20published%20in%20a%20newspaper.%20Such%20a%20pollusually%20specifies%20how%20many%20people%20were%20interviewed.%20This%20number%20is%20significant%20because,%20evenif%20the%20polling%20was%20done%20without%20bias,%20which%20is%20extremely%20unlikely,%20the%20laws%20of%20statistics%20say%20thatthere%20is%20a%20intrinsic%20error%20(in%20the%20fraction%20of%20people%20who%20supposedly%20support%20a%20given%20opinion)%20oforder%20one%20over%20the%20square%20root%20of%20the%20number%20of%20people%20questioned.%20It%20follows%20that%20if%20a%20thousandpeople%20were%20interviewed,%20which%20is%20a%20typical%20number,%20then%20the%20error%20is%20at%20least%20three%20percent.%20Wecan%20easily%20appreciate%20that%20if%20we%20do%20statistics%20on%20a%20thermodynamic%20system%20containing%201024particlesthen%20we%20are%20going%20to%20obtain%20results%20that%20are%20valid%20to%20incredible%20accuracy.%20In%20fact,%20in%20most%20situations,we%20can%20forget%20that%20the%20results%20are%20statistical%20at%20all,%20and%20treat%20them%20as%20exact%20laws%20of%20physics.%20Forinstance,%20the%20familiar%20equation%20of%20state%20of%20an%20ideal%20gas,PV=%CE%BDRT(see%20Section%206.2),%20is%20actuallya%20statistical%20result.%20In%20other%20words,%20it%20relates%20the%20average%20pressure,%20and%20the%20average%20volume,%20to%20theaverage%20temperature.%20However,%20for%20one%20mole%20of%20gas,the%20relative%20statistical%20deviations%20from%20averagevalues%20are%20only%20about%2010%E2%88%9212,%20according%20to%20the%201/N1/2Alaw.%20Of%20course,%20it%20is%20virtually%20impossible%20tomeasure%20the%20pressure,%20volume,%20or%20temperature%20of%20a%20gas%20to%20such%20accuracy,%20so%20it%20is%20often%20convenientto%20forget%20about%20the%20fact%20that%20the%20ideal%20gas%20law%20is%20a%20statistical%20result,%20and%20treat%20it%20as%20a%20law%20of%20physicsinterrelating%20the%20actual%20pressure,%20volume,%20and%20temperature%20of%20an%20ideal%20gas)).   The important consideration is how big the statistical fluctuations in thermodynamic quantities are.  For most features, these scale with number of particles in the system $N$, like $N^{-1/2}$.  So describing things in this way provides the reader with information about what is important in a way that merely saying `$N$ is large` does not.

> Thermodynamic systems are ideally suited to a statistical approach, because of the enormous numbers of particles that they contain. Statistical arguments actually get more exact as the numbers involved get larger. For example, consider an opinion poll published in a newspaper. Such a poll usually specifies how many people were interviewed. This number is significant because, even if the polling was done without bias, which is extremely unlikely, the laws of statistics say that there is a intrinsic error (in the fraction of people who supposedly support a given opinion) of order one over the square root of the number of people questioned. It follows that if a thousand people were interviewed, which is a typical number, then the error is at least three percent. We can easily appreciate that if we do statistics on a thermodynamic system containing $10^{24}$ particlesthen we are going to obtain results that are valid to incredible accuracy. In fact, in most situations,we can forget that the results are statistical at all, and treat them as exact laws of physics. For instance, the familiar equation of state of an ideal gas, $PV=νRT$(see Section 6.2), is actually a statistical result. In other words, it relates the average pressure, and the average volume, to the average temperature. However, for one mole of gas,the relative statistical deviations from average values are only about $10−12$, according to the $1/N^{1/2}_A$ law. Of course, it is virtually impossible to measure the pressure, volume, or temperature of a gas to such accuracy, so it is often convenient to forget about the fact that the ideal gas law is a statistical result, and treat it as a law of physics interrelating the actual pressure, volume, and temperature of an ideal gas

Answer (score 0):

> Is this definition scientific and popular? How can I find its source or probable proof?

I would say Yes! As for proof, I don't think there is any. But It uses the following reasoning.

If you look at the binomial distribution which is a discrete probability distribution $P(n,k)$ of getting $k$ successes from $n$ independent Bernoulli trials.
$$P(n,k)=\sideset{^n}{_k}C p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
It's turn out that
$$\langle k\rangle=np ,\ \ \ \ \sigma_k^2=np(1-p)$$
The fractional width of the distribution is obtained by the standard deviation by the mean and is given by
$$\frac{\sigma_k}{\langle k\rangle}=\sqrt{\frac{1-p}{np}}\propto\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
and therefore decreases as $n$ increases. This cause the binomial distribution to become more sharply peaked near the mean value as $n$ increase.

Now if recall that thermodynamics is just a time-independent average of statistical mechanics. Also that the thermodynamics deal with macroscopic quantities like pressure etc. Now if the fluctuation around means is very small one can system as a macroscopic system. That suggests that if
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<<1$$
We can treat the system as a thermodynamical system without caring about the fluctuation in the mean. Or equivalently as a macroscopic system.

---

> If we re-write the inequality, we will conclude: $N>>1$ So, why don't people write the inequality in this form? And why they twist it to a more complicated form?

Note $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<<1$$
and $$n<<1$$ are two different things.

For example suppose $n=100$,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{100}}=0.1$$
which not too small as compared to $1$ but
$$\frac{1}{100}<<1\Rightarrow 0.01<<1$$
is true. What I mean is that inequality is true but we want the number to be very small to $1$. As you can see $100$ and $\sqrt{100}$ have a difference of factor $10$ which means we are allowing $10$ times more fluctuation and as $n$ will increase this condition will fail (your one).

---

> Is there a more accurate definition for macroscopic and microscopic systems invalid physics references?

I don't know what do you mean by that. But You see there is no sharp boundary between the two regimes. It's more like those pictures where you start from one side as blue and as you go toward another side it becomes more reddish and eventually, there is no blue. It depends on your consideration and the accuracy you want.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer :-)